# Tizen supported devices

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I have built and deployed a wearable Tizen web app to my Gear S2. I know it works. When I upload it to the Tizen seller's store the list of supported devices is only a couple of phones. How can I get the supported device list to show me the wearables? There aren't any options showing up for that at the moment.

Comment: You didnt consider consulting google? Tizen is still in its infancy, so devices are very limited.

Comment: Of course I consulted google. I also submitted a ticket to Tizen's support desk. Your answer is not helpful.

Comment: This is not a programming related question and is a poor fit for the website - [Review this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you haven't programmed for Tizen before then how do you know it isn't a programming question? For all you know there is something wrong within my application which is preventing it from showing the correct device targets.

Comment: Per your link above, "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." which this does.

Comment: You havent posted anything that might identify potential problems, so other than a list of manufacturers who have made tizen devices - which is an off site resource - what help exactly were you expecting?

Comment: I don't know how to identify those potential problems, hence why I came here. If I knew how then I would do it myself and wouldn't be asking, would I? I told them I made a tizen app and the wrong devices are showing up. What else do you need to know? When building a mobile application one must always specify target devices.

Comment: How can you expect others to identify the problem with no source to work with? I'm not being difficult, I'm just pointing out what makes a good question. Better to wait for a response from tizen support

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Samsung has multiple different stores through which to sell Tizen apps.

Only one of those stores will sell wearable apps. The correct store to sell gear apps is the Samsung Apps Seller Store:
http://seller.samsungapps.com/

In the Tizen Seller Store you can upload wearable apps but you cannot specify them as target devices for deployment (despite having disabled dropdown options for it). It is only meant for Tizen phones.
http://seller.tizenstore.com/